# Mixing C++ compiler in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, openmp

In my VC++ project, I have a source file containing openMP code. Is it possible to compile only this file using intel compiler and the rest of my source files with VC++ compiler? Of course, the final output (.exe. or .dll) should be created by VC++ linker combining all the obj files including the one produced by intel compiler.

I am using VS 2019 v16.x